# Leverage ASP.NET Sessions in WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, session

I have the following configuration at the service side

```
<system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
   <sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" mode="InProc"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
         <binding name="ws">
            <security mode="None" />
            <reliableSession enabled="true" />
         </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
       <service name="WCFSvc.WCFSvc">
           <endpoint name="endPoint1"
               address="http://localhost:60219/Service1.svc" 
               binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ws"
               contract="WCFSvc.IWCFSvc" />
       </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
                               multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" >
```

As you can see that I'm using `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"`. I'm using a `wsHttpBinding` with reliable session enabled.

At the client side I also have enabled cookies to be used

My `InstanceContextMode` is `PerSession`, and the session mode on the service contract is  `SessionMode = SessionMode.Required`

Concurrency mode is single

I have one operation contract with `IsInitiating` property set to true and for others I've explicitly set them to false since the default is true (I thought this was the catch for the problem but NO!!!)

With all this in place, I've only been able to achieve WCF level sessions. i.e. The `OperationContext.Current.Session ID` remains the same between different calls to the service but the `HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID` keeps varying for every request!

But I want to leverage the ASP.NET sessions using the ASP.NET Compatibility Mode for which I need the `HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID` to be the same for consecutive requests within a single session.

So, What additional things should I do to achieve that?

Comment: [This should help](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2010/02/21/using-asp-net-sessions-from-wcf.aspx). Or did you use it already?

Comment: Editing your question by adding a space to "bump" it is not good etiquette.  Perhaps you should instead answer the questions people ask of you if you want help.  Others will see that you are not responsive to questions and not bother helping you.

Comment: @Marcel Thanks! That helped. But that post wasn't very obvious at first, and so I'm thinking of adding some descriptions to it and posting it as the answer here, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the catch was the absence of the browser! The ASP.NET is setting the session ID, but it is the job of the browser to send the same session ID in the request headers for each subsequent requests. The WCF client does not do this. Hence, we get a new session ID for each new request.

So, the fix is to set the session ID that is sent in the response from ASP.NET in each of the request manually. How do we do this?  We set it in the `OutgoingMessageProperties` like this...

```
 HttpResponseMessageProperty responseProperty = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name]
                   as HttpResponseMessageProperty;
 HttpSessionCookieHelper helper = HttpSessionCookieHelper.Create((string)responseProperty.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie]);

            HttpRequestMessageProperty requestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            helper.AddSessionIdToRequest(requestProperty);
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestProperty;
```

For the code to `HttpSessionCookieHelper` class and more information, refer to the blog mentioned by *Marcel* [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2010/02/21/using-asp-net-sessions-from-wcf.aspx/)